# Alternative expressions to 'you have to trust me''

Tags: speech

In novels, movies etc. especially when someone asks or tells to do something rather risky, new etc. they say 'you have to trust me' which sounds a bit *dramatic* to me.  What  alternatives for this expression for everyday, common usage can you suggest?

Comment: That's because it **is** dramatic. That's the point. You have no evidence you can present, so you're appealing to their trust. As a rhetorical or confidence strategy, it sometimes works because many people find a frank confession of lack of evidence -- giving away a potential advantage, in other words -- more convincing, as if telling the truth once guarantees one always tells the truth. But it's a strategy, not a grammatical phenomenon.

Comment: "If I always told you the truth, I wouldn't need you to trust me."

Comment: That does rather depend on *whose* "truth" we're talking about. You may sincerely believe what you're telling me is true (for example, if you're trying to persuade me that *your* god is the only or "best" one to worship). But you might be wrong, and I may have good reason to know or suspect that, without any implication that I think you're deliberately *lying*.

Answer (score 4):

Some possible alternatives :

- Have faith in me.
- Count on me.
- Keep faith in me.

But yes as John said expressions like this will sound dramatic either way so does not really matter which you choose.. just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *bank on* and *put/[**take stock in**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+stock)*.

> [**bank on (someone/something)**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bank-on): to depend on something happening or someone doing something: They're banking on [=counting on] him to find a solution to the problem.
>
> [**put/take stock in**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/put-stock-in): to have faith in, give credence to, or attribute real significance to.

Answer (score 2):

[to rely on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rely+on)  can be a common alternative.

- put trust in with confidence; "she is someone you can really rely on when times get rough"; "you can rely on his discretion"

Answer (score 2):

"Take my word for it," or, perhaps more casually, "You'll have to take my word for it."

Answer (score 1):

I think it may sound especially dramatic because you have concatenated, or maybe "portmanteau'd" two similar expressions. Specifically, this

> you have to trust me

and

> trust me on this

became [Alternative expressions to 'you have to trust me''](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171136/you-have-to-trust-me-on-this) per your question title. I am not criticizing the combination, but it may lessen the intensity by using one or the other rather than both.

Comment: Your portmantoad idea is quite a hop. :)

Comment: @tchrist Yes, and it isn't even ngram'd for accuracy! I read this, http://www.newrepublic.com/article/117428/limits-digital-humanities-adam-kirsch and am feeling more ad hoc lately.